# Fedora 23 passwordless ssh key not working in automated host addition

Tags: shell, ssh, key, fedora, password-less

I have installed Fedora 23 and have tried to do a passwordless login with:

```
# ssh-copy-id ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub user@host
```

which successfully copies the key to the host machine and I have checked in the host machine in:

```
# tail -n10 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

and my PC name exists as the last line but when trying to login:

```
# ssh user@host
```

I am asked for a password! I have tried to login to Ubuntu and CentOS and get the same result. I have done this previously with multiple linux distros including Fedora 21, CentOS and Ubuntu and it works just fine.

I need this to do finish the automated host addition script which adds a host and then logs in automatically (add_user_host):

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh-copy-id ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub $1@$2;
ssh $1@$2;
```

all you would do is run:

```
# add_user_host user host
```

Comment: I see that I have -2 seems like my question was too hard to reply to :)

Comment: look at this post here which seems to have a similar issue:

https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2015-November/466241.html

Comment: I wouldn't classify it as "too-hard", just off topic.

Comment: The previously added tags seemed to fit perfectly in the puzzle. I wouldn't mind someone giving me a down vote as this is my first question but would prefer to see his/her rationality or reasoning on why it was done. So now how is it "off topic"?

Comment: Because it is nothing to do with programming. It's a question about how to use your computer.

Comment: Im sorry TZHX but the last time I checked shell scripting is programming language. You can learn more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script :)

Comment: Your question isn't about shell scripting though, it's about how to log into a machine. Just because you're using the command line doesn't make what you're doing programming.

Comment: My question is how to log into a machine using shell. You can put those lines in a shell script and it becomes a program.

Comment: Jakuje seemed to have give the right answer. If this question still seems to be "off topic" then that is OK because I got my answer from the gentlemen below which is what I came for. If closing my post just because you can then I give the thumbs up, but if just need to ensure quality of stackoverflow professionally then I assume it will reopen other wise a more informative professional response will show up.

Keep up the good work! :)

Comment: If my question closes then that would mean I have seen so many nice functions of stackoverflow... Is there deleted or does it stay in the DB as a souvenir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Openssh-7.0 obsoleted DSA keys. To use them you need to specify `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-dss` in your `ssh_config` (as mentioned in your [linked thread](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2015-November/466244.html)) to make them working, or rather use other keys (RSA, ed25519).

This case has also its [page on official webseite](http://openssh.com/legacy.html) and part in [release notes](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.0).

Comment: I want to try this as soon as I get on my fedora machine. I would give you a +1 vote up but I just signed up yesterday.